# What is the fastest way to get a process name from a process id in C#

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory, process

I have the Windows process ID (`PID`) of a bunch of running programs in C#, and I need to know the process name (e.g. `chrome`) for informational display.

I currently use this approach:

```
string processName;
using(var process = Process.GetProcessById(pid))
{
  processName = process.ProcessName; // THIS is costly
}
```

It turns out it's one of the slowest function and most memory intensive in my diagnostics (according to Visual Studio Performance and Diagnostics). As an example, 70 calls requires 12.8 MB of memory. That's half of the total memory required by my app.

What are alternative (and faster) ways of getting a process name (OR a useful process description) from C#?

**Note: The code should run without administrator privileges**

Comment: You'll want to call Dispose() on the process object returned by GetProcessById(). Try adding in the call to Dispose() and benchmarking it again.

Comment: I already am. Updated my question to show it; it's `.ProcessName` that is costly.

Comment: About the down vote: How is this question unclear or not useful? Please let me know what to add / change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is designed for that purpose so if you're not satisfied with what it offers, on the startup of your application you can generate a cache, simple map of running processes, to provide yourself a source of fast access. For the processes which has started or stopped later - monitor appropriate events and refresh the map accordingly, e.g. using WMI:

```
private IDictionary<int, string> _map;
private ManagementEventWatcher _watcher;

_watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher("SELECT ProcessID, ProcessName FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace");
_watcher.EventArrived += ProcessStarted;            
_watcher.Start();

private void ProcessStarted(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    // add proc to _map
}
```

Comment: I need to get the current list of processes, but I'll certainly try WMI to get all process names in one go. I'll get back with results later today.

Comment: I implemented code that queried WMI for the list of processes, and got something that ran 3 times slower than `Process.GetProcessById`; then I realized that you meant: keeping a live list of processes as they start rather than on-demand! I think that's an amazing idea, but it requires running with elevated privileges... I'll add this requirement to my question.

Comment: Either there is no faster solution, or I couldn't find an alternative so here's the accepted answer. Even if the answer will not work for users not running as administrator, it will at least be faster if they do. Thanks.